# import json files from gcloud storage into Firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-storage

We manage to produce lots of large json files ~600MB+ (with one json record per line) and we want to import this into Firebase database. Is there any way to do this directly using a `gs://` path?

(The fire base console UI has an import function but this is using json from local files not `gs://` and `https://github.com/firebase/firebase-import` is not clear whether is can work from Google Storage.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct connection to import data from a file in Google Cloud Storage into the Firebase Database. You will have to use some intermediary tool or code for that. While recommending a specific tool is off-topic on Stack Overflow, I want to point out [Firebase's own streaming import tool](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-streaming-import) as one option

But you should really consider what purpose this import serves. The Firebase Database is a great tool for synchronizing data between connected clients. It is not a great tool for advanced querying or reporting on large data sets. Something like BigQuery is much more suited to such tasks.

Comment: The use case is to pre-load the database with lots of records such as products. There is no analytics or querying per say but one approach we tried was to use the REST API and load in parallel which works.